# Div nesting issue with Gumby framework grid

Tags: html, css, gumby-framework

Using the Gumby Framework I'm encountering issues nesting divs.

I'm trying to nest a three and seven column grid within a ten column grid.

I've tried a few variations with my HTML/CSS to no avail. Figure I must be missing something fairly simple.

[Site Link](http://portfolioprep.suissamesser.com)

HTML code example:

```
 <div class="ten columns main_col">
 <p>Text removed</p>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="three"><h2 class="100width">Core Services</h2></div>
 <div class="seven"></div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: What are you specifically trying to make this area of your page look like?

Comment: Just to mention: you can't use class names starting with number (100width).

Comment: Good catch! I know better too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework isn't "smart". Everything is based on 12 or 16 columns. So you've got to do all the thinking for things of this nature. If you want a 3-7 centered container within a 12 column grid, the following code does just that:

```
<!-- 10 Columns -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns push_one">3 col</div>
    <div class="seven columns">7 col</div>
</div>
<!-- // End 10 -->
```

Here's why: 10 columns = 10 of 12(for argument's sake), 3 columns and 7 columns within that container are actually a 30% of 12 column next to a 70% of 12 column residing inside a 83.333% of 12 column container. Throwing `class="ten columns"` on the container doesn't fire some kind of recursive function to "reset" the container as a 10 column grid system; thus,  the goofy margins, padding, etc. It's actually working as expected. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following you on this: The framework is using its normal percentage based values, but when it comes to nesting, 100% of the containing DIV isn't the equivalent to 100% of the 12 columns grid.

Comment: No, it is not 100% of the 12. It's now 100% of parent container 10, which is quite a bit narrower than 12. Easiest way to see this in action: `div { outline:1px dotted; margin:5% }`, then `<div id="1"><div id="2"><div id="3"></div></div></div>` Obviously, #3 will be much narrower than #1. To your dilemma, you could write some CSS to accomodate your one-off situations: `.ten.columns > .three.columns {...} .ten.columns > .seven.columns {...}`

Comment: Another method, if you don't like the one above: | 1 Col | 3 Col | 7 Col | 1 Col |. Still...it's up to you, the author, to wrap your head around how 10col actually works within the confines of that framework.

Comment: Thank you so much. My comments wasn't clear, I get now it's 100% of the 10 rather than the 12. So it all makes sense. Just thought initially that the framework was somehow able to account for that in the nesting. I think it's because we're used to using 960.gs

Comment: One more thing, as a generality is it even possible to match widths within nested grids? If 5 columns is 29.7% of the full 16 column grid I'm assuming in most cases it would be impossible to match the fixed width (280px with 5 columns) using columns in a nested grid?

Comment: It's absolutely possible, but the math makes my head hurt. Here's a simple design:** **http://jsfiddle.net/Ejzws/** **It's fluid (percentage based), and nested. (Keep in mind, all that CSS for just nesting a pair of singles.) - oh...and that last column is mislabeled as nested